# Perform keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know, how can I perform keydown on specified element or document. Now I need to perform 'click on right arrow'. I tried this: `$('#page').trigger({type: 'keydown', name: 'right'});`

But this doesn't work. Is here any solution, how can I perform action like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass custom event with key code for this:

```
var customEvent = jQuery.Event( 'keydown' );
customEvent.which = 39;
$( '#page' ).trigger( customEvent );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found better solution `$(document).trigger({type: 'keydown', keyCode: 37});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#element').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==39){
        //do anything here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Keydown function. More detail [here](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

```
$( '#page').keydown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
```